# Can't create a project with Xamarin on Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm having a problem with running the ios .cspoj file, when i want to start new project for iOS devices I get error that i have to install Xamarin. I have installed Xamarin program and still says that i need to install Xamarin for start ios project. I don't know what to do so i hope you guys can help me fix the problem.

Here is image of the problem

[image]

Comment: This happened to me when I installed VS 2017 RC + Xamarin after I had VS 2015 + Xamarin installed. Apparently, the Xamarin versions are not compatible with each other at the moment; so you can only install it for one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you installed the "Xamarin program", but what exactly did you install? I cannot tell from your screenshot if you are using Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015, but...

If you are using Visual Studio 2013, you will need to use the [Xamarin Universal Installer](https://www.xamarin.com/download)(Just input your information and the file will be available to download).

If you are using Visual Studio 2015, then you can install Xamarin directly from within the Visual Studio 2015 installer window. Using Microsoft's guide from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613162.aspx#Anchor_1) you can:

> - ...open **Control Panel > Programs and Features**, choose the **Visual Studio 2015** item, and click **Change**. When the installer opens, click **Modify**
> - Check the following boxes:
>
>   - **Cross-Platform Mobile Development > C#/.NET (Xamarin)**
>   - For Windows 8+: **Cross-Platform Mobile Development > Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android**
>   - (Optional) If you plan on targeting Windows devices, also check **Windows and Web Development > Universal Windows App Development Tools** and/or **Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools**
> - Click the Install button
> - Once installation is complete... check for Xamarin updates through  Tools > Options > Xamarin or **Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other**, where you’ll find a **Check Now**

Comment: From the screenshot, VS Community 2015 is installed.